# touch webView under CCGLView

Tags: ios, uiview, webview, cocos2d-iphone

I have a `webView` which is a `WKWebView` and a `CCGLView` contains all the cocos nodes. both of them are screen size. now I want the `webView` as a background and `CCGLView` on the top and shows some buttons. But the problem is when I touch on place where there is no buttons in `CCGLView`, it will still touch on the `CCGLView` instead of `webView`. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I tried to add the `ccglView` on top of `webView`, and `ccglView` as a child of  `webView`, but the touch always only happens on `ccglView`.

Comment: You have to find a way to "propagate" your touch from the CCGLView to your webView. Maybe catch them on CCGLView and call a method from your webView passing the coordinates of the touch